# Adding ISNULL into a small dynamic header script

Tags: sql, t-sql

We are using this small recursive script to create a string for the dynamic headers of a table - the variable feeds into a piece of dynamic sql.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #PivotStep1;
CREATE TABLE #PivotStep1(PlayMonth VARCHAR(25))
INSERT INTO #PivotStep1
    values
        ('01-oct-2016'),
        ('01-nov-2016'),
        ('01-dec-2016'),
        ('01-jan-2017'),
        ('01-feb-2017');


DECLARE @ColumnName AS nvarchar(MAX)


SELECT @ColumnName = ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
                      + QUOTENAME(PlayMonth)
FROM (
        SELECT  DISTINCT PlayMonth 
        FROM    #PivotStep1
    ) AS ps

SELECT @ColumnName;
```

The above gives the following:

```
[01-dec-2016],[01-feb-2017],[01-jan-2017],[01-nov-2016],[01-oct-2016]
```

What we want is to surround each column name with ISNULL and AS... So the desired output is the following:

```
ISNULL([01-dec-2016],0) AS [01-dec-2016],ISNULL([01-feb-2017],0) AS [01-feb-2017],ISNULL([01-jan-2017],0) AS [01-jan-2017],ISNULL([01-nov-2016],0) AS [01-nov-2016],ISNULL([01-oct-2016],0) AS [01-oct-2016]
```

We would like to keep using the above recursive approach rather than using STUFF and XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the quotename twice and do other required concatenation.

Try this:

```
select @ColumnName = ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',', '') 
      + 'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(PlayMonth) + ', 0) as ' + QUOTENAME(PlayMonth)
from (
    select distinct PlayMonth
    from #PivotStep1
    ) as ps

select @ColumnName;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/CMMX25339)